# How to extract infos in a .db file to create .csv or any viable "bookmark" file?

Tags: sqlite

I am using a quite unknown bookmark manager on Android. I picked this one after trying others because it was possible to import, export, classify by folders, the design was good and it was easy to search in my bookmarks.

After importing all my bookmarks from other browsers and also from files, I started classifying all of them into folders, subfolders, etc..

I spent many days to classify them all as I wanted.

After classifying them, I tried to export them.

The problem is that the only option offered is to export them in a .html file, containing all the bookmarks but without any folder.

The .html file contains all my bookmarks but in complete desorder, and doesnt mention the folders.

In the app there was also a "backup" function, so I tried and it creates a .db file.

I opened this .db file with some SQLiteViewer app and I found written inside, among other things I dont understand, a list of all my bookmarks with a number next to each one of them, and also a list of my folders with next to them the corresponding number.

When I open the .db file, I have a choice between
-SQlite master
-android metadata
-bookmarks
-folders
-sqlite sequence

If I click on "Bookmarks", all my bookmarks are in a kind of spreadsheet with lines and columns. Next to them in another columns, for example for each bookmark related with "Kitchen recipes" it's written the number 1.
And in the "Folders" folder, next to the folder called "Recipes" its also written 1.

So I'm happy because it seems that my classification is stored in this file.

But the fact is I dont know how to extract easily all that data, and create with it a "bookmark" file importable in other bookmark app or browser ( for example .csv or .xbel or .html but with folders)

I guess I need some "script" working like this:
if the first raw in "Folders" got the number 8 next to it
Then take all the bookmarks in the "bookmarks" folder that also got an 8 written next to it, and put it inside this folder.

I'm a complete noob in coding, I dont know what is SQlite, nor anything.
So i know that maybe I am asking for too much informations at the same time.

But if some kind person could put me in the way, by explaining me if

1. thats possible
2. what would be the easiest way
3. if some solution already exist
4. if someone like me can do it and what do I have to learn if I want some day to be able to do it

Thanks

Here's pictures so you understand easier:
[Sqlite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFEp.jpg)

[Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgV66.jpg)

[Bookmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG55r.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You should start reading on how to use SQLite in a language you're familiar with, and research how to perform queries on your database and output to some format like a .csv.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm currently learning Javascript so I guess I'll learn how to use SQLite with Javascript when I'll be more confident with its use.